# Web Service retrofit parsing

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

what is wrong with this retrofit ? request is success but no values are get

this is how my json looks like

```
 [
    {
        "msg": "test",
        "time": "2017-06-20 00:39:31",
        "kind": "txt"
    },
    {
        "msg": "مرحبا يا برو",
        "time": "2017-06-20 00:40:02",
        "kind": "txt"
    },
    {
        "msg": "url",
        "time": "2017-06-20 01:57:12",
        "kind": "img"
    },
    {
        "msg": "url",
        "time": "2017-06-20 01:58:54",
        "kind": "video"
    }
]
```

AllMessagesResponse class

```
public class AllMessagesResponse {

    public ArrayList<MessagesInfo> getMessagesInfos() {
        return messagesInfos;
    }

    private ArrayList<MessagesInfo>messagesInfos=new ArrayList<>();

}
```

MessageInfo class

```
public class MessagesInfo{

    @SerializedName("time")
    private String time;

    @SerializedName("msg")
    private String msgs;

    @SerializedName("kind")
    private String kind;

    @SerializedName("sender")
    private String senderID;

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getMsgs() {
        return msgs;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public String getSenderID() {
        return senderID;
    }
}
```

API class

```
@POST("chat/veiwPeerToPeer.php")
    Call<AllMessagesResponse>getMessages(@Body AllMessages allMessages);
```

Main Activity class

```
AllMessages allMessages=new AllMessages();
        allMessages.senderID=MainActivity.userId;
        allMessages.receiverID=receiverId;
        WebService.getInstance().getApi().getMessages(allMessages).enqueue(new Callback<AllMessagesResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AllMessagesResponse> call, Response<AllMessagesResponse> response) {
                AllMessagesResponse allMessagesResponse=response.body();
                setTitle(String.valueOf(allMessagesResponse.getMessagesInfos().size()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AllMessagesResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

onResponse is working but I get no values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need another pojo for list you can directly request for list Retrofit directly provide list.

```
Call<List<POJO>>
```

I fetch the same JSON response like you did. [SEE URL](http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json)

```
apiInterface = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(BASE_URL_ANDROIDHIVE)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build().create(ApiInterface.class);

                final Call<List<AndroidHive>> hiveCall = apiInterface.getAllMovies();

                hiveCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<AndroidHive>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<AndroidHive>> call, Response<List<AndroidHive>> response) {

                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            List<AndroidHive> hiveList = response.body();

                            tv_retrofit.setText("Title : " + hiveList.get(3).getTitle() + "\n Image : " + hiveList.get(3).getImage() + "\n Rating : " + hiveList.get(3).getRating() + " \n Release Year : " + hiveList.get(3).getReleaseYear() + "\n  Gener : " + hiveList.get(3).getGenre());

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Response Failed Code : " + response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<AndroidHive>> call, Throwable t) {
                        System.out.println(t.getStackTrace().toString());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```